# Chrome is unresponsive with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

When I start a project (with or without debugging) in Visual Studio 2017, I get the error: **google chrome is unresponsive. relaunch now?**

I have disabled the Javascript debugging for .NET, but that hasn't helped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm also getting this annoying problem just clicking any any link from inside Visual Studio. The "Web Portal" link, any "more information" links when viewing extensions in "Extensions and Updates" etc

Comment: I have the same problem. Really annoying. Any solutions?

Comment: I've see this issue intermittently over the past year or so and it is always associated with starting Chrome from Visual Studio 2017. Seems to mostly occur when using context menu option 'View in Browser' of a .cshtml page.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is an old link but I think I should answer this. I also encountered this weird error sometime back. I think it is related to IIS. Once you have started IIS along with visual studio this error springs up. Try closing the IIS,Chrome and restart visual studio. It will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch Chrome manually
2. Click on the three dots on the top right hand corner of the browser
3. Go down to *Help*->*About Google Chrome*. The About screen will display
4. Close Chrome and try again

It worked or me. Strange, but it worked.